# Is there a way to directly use Enums with the tagfield in extjs?

Tags: extjs

I have to create multiselect combobox. I have a plain combobox which loads its data using Enums. This is working fine. But I have to allow multiselect in this combobox for which I have changed the xtype from combobox to tagfield. But the list is not populated because the tagfield requires store and in my case I'm fetching values from an Enum class which returns values in following format:

```
[{label: "label1",value: "value1"},
{label: "label2",value: "value2"}]
```

How can I use tagfield with enums?

My code goes something like this:

```
tbar : {
    items : [ {
       xtype : 'container',
       layout : 'hbox',
       items : [ {
          xtype : 'combobox',
          labelWidth : 150
       }]
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? Why you don't want to use a store?

Comment: I can use store, but the problem is that I’m the existing code base I get data from enums

Comment: Is there is anyway that we can use enum data in store and use it in tagfield?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't understand correctly your question, but if your data is returned like

```
[{label: "label1",value: "value1"},
{label: "label2",value: "value2"}]
```

You can define your `tagfield` like this:

```
//get ref of your data
let myData = [{
    label: "label1",
    value: "value1"
        }, {
    label: "label2",
    value: "value2"
        }]
```

And

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tagfield',
        store: {
            storeId: 'MyStoreId',
            data: myData //set the data in the store
        },
        labelWidth: 150,
        displayField: 'label',
        valueField: 'value'
     }]
}]
```